# How to evaluate a test?

Tags: sml

If I have this test defined like:

```
val neg = Test (fn x => x < 0, "neg");
```

How do I test this?
I tried

```
neg 3;
```

but I get an error...

Comment: Perhaps for the future you could include the actual code and error. At least that will give people a chance to help your out!

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, `Test` is a value constructor, and thus you should "unwrap" it before you can access the pair inside.

Something like this ought to do the job

```
val Test (f, s) = Test (fn x => x < 0, "neg")
f 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by having a function that unwraps the test and runs it:

```
fun runtest Test(f,s) x = f x
```

You would then do

```
runtest neg 3
```